# OpenGL Maximal amount of debug string reached

Tags: opengl

I was trying to check my current openGL code in gDEBugger, everything works fine.
But, I get these messages

```
Debug String: >>>>>>>>> 1
Debug String: >>>>>>>>> 2
Debug String: >>>>>>>>> 3
...
Debug String: >>>>>>>>> 497
Debug String: Maximal amount of debug string reached (500 strings). 
              Additional debug strings will be ignored
```

What are these messages, everything in my code runs fine. But its troubling to see these debug strings.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like OpenGL is generating debug warnings/errors in its internal queue, and you are never retrieving them, so they just pile up until they reach the limit of 500.

To fix it, you can provide a callback function for OpenGL to inform you whenever it generates one of these messages, rather than putting it on the queue.  Or you can query the queue at regular intervals (e.g. once a frame, assuming you don't generate 500 messages in a single frame), and clear out the old messages to make room for new ones.

For more details, see the [GL_ARB_debug_output spec](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/debug_output.txt).

Comment: Im using the below extension already                                     -                              if(glewIsSupported("GL_ARB_debug_output"))
{
 glDebugMessageCallback(&DebugCallBack, NULL);
 glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT_SYNCHRONOUS_ARB);
}                                                                       and im not seeing any debug callback happening, but in gDEBugger i see those error messages, what else am i missing apart from the above?

Comment: Its really difficult to post code in the comments ... posting the question has flexibility, but not in comments :(

Comment: you can edit your question and add code.